# Summation of 3 different workbooks Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3 workbooks each with a column Stock in them that I need to sum up using a macro. These workbooks are not uniform in style which is what makes this tricky. Workbook1 has it in column J, workbook2 has it in column I, and workbook3 has it in column G. On top of that they need to sum up according to the sku numbers, workbook1 has SKU in column C, workbook2 has it in column C, but workbook3 has it in column D.

Note: I need the new workbook to be titles LX03

Could anyone assist me with this issue?

I am a complete beginner. I understand how to declare variables in VBA, but after a good few hours of online searching I can not seem to figure how to code the IF statements necessary for the criteria regarding my situation.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say after the summation I've been trying to figure out how to make the macro title the file LX03.

Answer (score 0):

I am not the best with VBA yet either, but I may have a solution for you. A combination of Vlookup and just simple VBA/macro.

VLookup will allow you to lookup stock based on the SKU for each workbook. Basically, all I can really advise is lookup how to use Vlookup and it may be helpful, although it does depend on your use case. I was doing something similar last week and it worked out great.